# Why did Wormtail not turn Voldemort over to the Ministry or the Order?

Tags: harry-potter

Wormtail had miserable time with Voldemort, wasn't even actually loyal to him and only had found and returned to him because he "had nowhere else to go". What's more, he couldn't even hope to rise in ranks or gain any favors because of his general ineptitude and clumsy care he gives to Voldermort, and I suppose while not a really bright person, he surely knows once the Dark Lord regains strength and other Death Eaters rejoin him, everyone will push him around because of low opinion of him, so he has little reason to actually go through all of this, right?

But isn't there an obvious way to end his suffering and even redeem himself? He helped to create a rudimentary body for the Dark Lord, however, he still depended on Wormtail entirely, as he himself admitted, even going as far as to state he needs to be fed once every few hours, **and couldn't even hold and use his wand** as it seems because Wormtail was the one who used it before Voldemort regained his former body. There was Nagini, but surely a man who can blow the whole street up with his wand behind his back and kill several bystanders could devise something to smuggle Voldemort out, like, say, disapparating while feeding? Even if Voldemort senses or knows Wormtail is up to no good, what options does he have? He can only command his snake to defend him, but that probably requires more time than is needed to disapparate or subdue Nagini itself. Plus, I think it's a given that Nagini isn't always present, after all, it needs to feed itself somehow, and the most obvious way would be to go hunting, thereby leaving the Dark Lord alone with Wormtail.

We know that ratting out other Death Eaters is how many of them escaped harsh punishment, surely handing Voldemort himself over to the Ministry would absolve any and all wrongdoings Peter might be accused of, if at all, given he is regarded actually as a sort of a hero post-mortem. He might even claim he had to go into hiding in order to find Voldemort's whereabouts and capture him, which he does after so many years at last. Also, given his personality, I think it would be quite in character not to look up to Voldemort in his pitiful condition, *having lost all his power*, and instead seek other opportunities to establish his significance and power. After all, what's betraying once more?

Having said that, is there a compelling reason this didn't happen that I don't see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because that is Wormtail's nature.**

Wormtail could have chosen when Voldemort had "died" to face justice and barter for his freedom by naming more important Death Eaters then. Instead, he chose to go into hiding as a pet rat for the rest of his life. This could not have been a very pleasant life for him either, as it would be insanely boring, lacking in human companionship, and lacking in freedom to do as he wanted. But he chose it because he is the type of person that will choose what he believes is the safest path, no matter how unpleasant it is.

In other words, Wormtail is fundamentally a coward who has no confidence in his own ability, so ingratiates himself to others he believes will protect him.

It didn't matter that he was capable of fairly impressive magic, as he still felt himself to be incapable and needing protection, first by James and his friends, then Voldemort. Wormtail was clearly convinced if he was discovered alive, it would condemn him as a Death Eater to the Ministry and a traitor to the other Death Eaters. Therefore, he felt the only one left that he could depend on to take him in then was Voldemort who he knew could not turn him away because he needed help, and Voldemort could in turn protect him from the Death Eaters and the Ministry.

Once taken in, he would never betray Voldemort unless he were put into a position where he felt that continuing to serve Voldemort had become more dangerous than betraying him, or perhaps if he found another protector he felt could keep him safe from the many enemies he'd collected. And even then, he would surely attempt to weasel his way out rather than directly betray Voldemort if he had such an option. Such seemed to be the case with his betrayal of Lilly and James, where he had decided that Voldemort had become too strong, and therefore it was safer to ally himself with him than stay on what he believed was the losing side. His later betrayal of Voldemort was again because Voldemort could no longer protect him due to having been "killed" by Harry Potter.